# Take User input to perform calculation in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have written this piece of code but it is not working. I want to use the value entered by user to perform following calculation...

```js
function calculateBasic()
  {
   var uservalue = form.size.value;
   var powerForOrganic = Math.pow(uservalue,1.05);
   var effortForOrganic = 2.4 * power;
   var powerTdevOrganic = Math.pow(effortForOrganic,0.38);
   var tdevForOrganic =  2.5 * powerTdevOrganic;
   var averageStaffForOrganic = effortForOrganic / tdevForOrganic;
   var productivityLevelForOrganic = averageStaffForOrganic / effortForOrganic;
   alert( "Effort :" + effortForOrganic + "TDEV :" + tdevForOrganic + "Average Staff :" + averageStaffForOrganic + "Productivity :" + productivityLevelForOrganic);
   
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="size" placeholder="Enter the size in KLOC">
<input type="button" id="enterInfo" Value="Submit"  onclick="calculateBasic(this.form);">
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("size").value`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line should be

```
var uservalue = document.getElementById("size").value;
```

`power` also wasn't defined. You probably meant `powerForOrganic`, which was defined the line before.

```
var effortForOrganic = 2.4 * powerForOrganic;
```

Here is the complete code

```
function calculateBasic() {
    var uservalue = Number(document.getElementById("size").value);
    var powerForOrganic = Number(Math.pow(uservalue,1.05));
    var effortForOrganic = Number(2.4 * powerForOrganic);
    var powerTdevOrganic = Number(Math.pow(effortForOrganic,0.38));
    var tdevForOrganic =  Number(2.5 * powerTdevOrganic);
    var averageStaffForOrganic = effortForOrganic / tdevForOrganic;
    var productivityLevelForOrganic = averageStaffForOrganic / effortForOrganic;
    alert( "Effort :" + effortForOrganic + "TDEV :" + tdevForOrganic + "Average Staff :" + averageStaffForOrganic + "Productivity :" + productivityLevelForOrganic);

    }

var button = document.getElementById("enterInfo");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    calculateBasic();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/739amacp/

Comment: Also @M.Nabeel you have to change the html: `onclick="calculateBasic();"`

Answer (score 0):

On line 4 you reference `power` when I believe you intended to reference `powerForOrganic`.

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me the olden days of programming with javascript. It is still valid.

1) You are passing form as argument to the function, but the function doesn't get it.
2) some variable you are using inside the function is not declared or available.
3) If you are getting values of form as form..value, then you should give name for that element.

```js
function calculateBasic(form)
  {
   var uservalue = (form.size.value);
   var powerForOrganic = Math.pow(uservalue,1.05);
   var effortForOrganic = 2.4 * powerForOrganic;
   var powerTdevOrganic = Math.pow(effortForOrganic,0.38);
   var tdevForOrganic =  2.5 * powerTdevOrganic;
   var averageStaffForOrganic = effortForOrganic / tdevForOrganic;
   var productivityLevelForOrganic = averageStaffForOrganic / effortForOrganic;
   alert( "Effort :" + effortForOrganic + "TDEV :" + tdevForOrganic + "Average Staff :" + averageStaffForOrganic + "Productivity :" + productivityLevelForOrganic);
   
  }
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" name="size" id="size" placeholder="Enter the size in KLOC">
<input type="button" id="enterInfo" Value="Submit"  onclick="calculateBasic(this.form)">
    </form>
```